# How to use AppDelegate alternateView in Kobold2D to replace rootViewController

Tags: kobold2d, appdelegate

I want to create a Kobold2D app with a container view that will hold both the cocos2d CCDirector view and my own UIViews. I can see from documentation that this can be done using the alternateView method in the AppDelegate but I can't see how to use this method and what exactly it should return. Could you provide me with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should simply return a UIView. The "Cocos2D with UIKit Views" template project uses the alternateView method to create exactly this kind of container view:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

-(id) alternateView
{
    // we want to be a dummy view the self.view to which we add the glView plus all other UIKit views
    KKAppDelegate* appDelegate = (KKAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    // add a dummy UIView to the view controller, which in turn will have the glView and later other UIKit views added to it
    CGRect bounds = [appDelegate.window bounds];
    UIView* dummyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
    [dummyView addSubview:[CCDirector sharedDirector].view];

    return dummyView;
}

@end
```

This code goes in your project's **AppDelegate.m**

Comment: Thanks Steffen. As a Kobold2D newbie, sometimes the 'obvious' is just not obvious. Now I can see the structure that really helps.

Comment: Hi again. I've tried putting this code into alternateView and put a breakpoint in it, but it looks like the function never gets called. Is there a switch/config that needs setting to make sure that alternateView gets called?

Comment: Hi Paul, have you found a solution?